# How to show posts of only the logged in user from firestore in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show the posts of only logged in user in my dashboard. I'm creating a todo app where authenticated users can only see their todo list. I know I have to link the uid from auth with the firestore documents but I don't know the process.

Component where I add a new todo to the firestore and fetch the todos with snapshot method and send it to another component as props for rendering :

```
function Dash() {
  const [todo, setTodo ] = useState('');
  const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
  const [ todos, setTodos ] = useState([]);
  const ref = db.collection('todos');
  useEffect(() => {
    return ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      const list = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const { text, done } = doc.data();
        list.push({
          id: doc.id,
          text,
          done,
        });
      });

      setTodos(list);

      if (loading) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);
  
  async function addTodo() {
   await ref.add({
      done: false,
      text: todo,
      
    });

    setTodo('');
  }
  return(
  <>
  <Appbar>
    <Appbar.Content title={'TODOs List'} />
  </Appbar>
  <FlatList
        style={{flex: 1}}
        data={todos}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Todo {...item} />}
      />

 
  <TextInput label={'New Todo'} value={todo} onChangeText={(text) => setTodo(text)} />
  <Button onPress={() => addTodo()}>Add TODO</Button>
</>
  );
}
```

Component where I render the todos and display it in a List:

```
import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, View, CheckBox, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { db }  from '../firebase/fire';
import { List, Button, Divider, Provider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { auth } from '../firebase/fire';
import {
  Menu,
  MenuOptions,
  MenuOption,
  MenuTrigger,
} from 'react-native-popup-menu';


function Todo({ id, text, done}) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [visible, setVisible]= useState(false);
  const openMenu =() => setVisible(true);
  const closeMenu =() => setVisible(false);


  function deleteDoc(){
    db.collection('todos').doc(id).delete();
  }
  async function toggleComplete() {
    try{

    await db
      .collection('todos')
      .doc(id)
      .update({
        done: !done,
      
      });}
      catch
        (err){
          console.log(err);
        }
      }

  return (
    <List.Item
      title={text}
      left={props => (
        <Button {...props} icon={done ? 'check' : 'cancel'} onPress={() => toggleComplete()}/>
      )}
      right={()=>(
        <Button  icon='delete' onPress={() => deleteDoc()}/>
      )}
    />
    
  );
}
export default React.memo(Todo);
```

Comment: Hello, any updates on the issue? If my answer was useful you can accept (✔) and upvote () it. [What should I do when someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hi, im currently working on other things right now. I'll get back to you soon thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First, you would have to store UID of user in every new todo (document) that a user creates. Let's say we call that field 'userID'. Then you can query documents where that `userID` field is set to UID of current user.

To get UID of current user:

```js
const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
```

Query to fetch user's documents:

```js
const ref = db.collection("todos").where("userID", "==", uid)
ref.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  const list = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const { text, done } = doc.data();
    list.push({
      id: doc.id,
      text,
      done,
    });
  });
  setTodos(list);
})
```

To make sure users can read/write their own documents, set proper security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /todos/{todoID} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah i get the part where you check userID with the current uid. but I have problem adding UID of user in every new todo (document) that user creates. I already have a collection named todos where there are many documents containing texts and a boolean field of isCompleted. How can I add a userID field there?

Comment: @arpandhakal just write the code to fetch IDs of all existing todos, then update all of them with the new field... If you are adding a kind of new feature in your app then you need to do that...

Comment: or should i just create a new collection with userID field and others?

Comment: @arpandhakal depends on your requirements. You should ask a separate question for that as it sounds off topic to this one.